# Mapping through multiple possible values in an object - React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I currently have a component that takes a currencyCode and returns an SVG of the corresponding country. I want to expand the component for instances whereby we want to search by country name and not by currency code. The current props that are passed into the component are:

currencyCode - which is something like "AED" &
countryLabel - which is something like "United Arab Emirates"

```
import Afghanistan from "./CountryFlags/Afghanistan.js";
// condensed imports

const currencyCodeMap = {
  AED: UnitedArabEmirates,
  AFN: Afghanistan,
  ALL: Albania,
  AMD: Armenia,
  AOA: Angola,
  ARS: Argentina,
  AUD: Australia,
  AZN: Azerbaijan,
};

type Props = {
  currencyCode?: string,
  countryLabel?: string,
  className?: string,
};

const CountryFlag = ({ currencyCode, countryLabel, className }: Props) => {
  const FlagComponent = currencyCodeMap[currencyCode];

  if (!FlagComponent) {
    return <StyledIcon isOberonIcon={true} name={"countryFallback"} />;
  }

  return (
    <StyledImageWrapper className={className}>
      <FlagComponent />
    </StyledImageWrapper>
  );
};
```

I tried to update my currencyCodeMap to something like:

`AED | "United Arab Emirates"` so that either the label or the code would return a flag, but no joy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AED | "United Arab Emirates"` is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Why not have an object like:

```
type CountryEntry = {
  currencyCode: string,
  countryLabel: string,
  flagComponent: JSX.Element
}
```

Then have an array of these and use `.find()` to get the component.

It would look something like this:

```
import Afghanistan from "./CountryFlags/Afghanistan.js";

type Props = {
  currencyCode?: string,
  countryLabel?: string,
  className?: string,
};

type CountryEntry = {
  currencyCode: string,
  countryLabel: string,
  flagComponent: JSX.Element
}

const flags: CountryEntry[] = [
  { currencyCode: "AFN", countryLabel: "Afghanistan", flagComponent: Afghanistan },
/* ... */
];

const CountryFlag = ({ currencyCode, countryLabel, className }: Props) => {
  const countryEntry = flags.find(
    (f) => f.countryLabel === countryLabel || f.currencyCode === currencyCode
  );

  if (!countryEntry) {
    return <StyledIcon isOberonIcon={true} name={"countryFallback"} />;
  } else {
    const FlagComponent = countryEntry.flagComponent;
    
    return (
      <StyledImageWrapper className={className}>
        <FlagComponent />
      </StyledImageWrapper>
    );
};
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. little confused what you mean by:

const flags:  CountryEntry[] = [/* ... */];

would you mind explaining a little further?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer. Let me know if it makes more sense now.

Comment: thanks for the amends, appreciate the help. the ".flagComponent" is causing issues at the end of the find method ("Cannot get `flags.find(...).flagComponent` because property `flagComponent` is missing in  undefined ")

Comment: Okay. I updated it again. Should be all good now.

Comment: thanks - works perfectly. appreciate the time!!